# Editing network interfaces without system rebooting

Tags: networking, network-manager

I'd like to make some changes to my networking configuration by editing my `/etc/network/interfaces` file. What's the cleanest way to make changes to this file and have them take effect, without having to reboot? Typically, I've been doing:

1. Edit the file
2. `service networking restart`

But I have the impression that this isn't the "right" way to make these kinds of changes.

Comment: service networking restart almost= /etc/init.d/networking restart.

Answer (score 14):

In Ubuntu Server 16.04 and above you must use [the `ip` command](http://www.policyrouting.org/iproute2.doc.html) ([man page](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/iproute2%20Task:%20minimal,%20ubuntu-core)) to flush the address before restarting networking, otherwise any address changes in the interfaces file will not take effect:

```
$ sudo ip addr flush interface-name
$ sudo systemctl restart networking
```

I got this answer from [this helpful article](http://www.configserverfirewall.com/ubuntu-linux/ubuntu-restart-network-interface/)

Comment: Perfect, this should be the answer to the question.

Answer (score 11):

Shut the network interface down using

```
sudo ifdown eth0
```

(replace `eth0` with the interface you want to change) and bring it up again using

```
sudo ifup eth0
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. It just gave me an error "eth0 not configured". I had to reboot the system for change to take effect on 12.04.

Comment: Careful, this won't work if you're connected over SSH (for obvious reasons).

Comment: @Ajedi32 just join them with && in a single line.

Answer (score 3):

Stop all interfaces using

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking stop
```

Configure (edit) your interfaces as you wish, then

Start them again

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking start
```

There is no need to reboot.

Comment: This didn't work either in Ubuntu 12.04. Only rebooting system worked.

Comment: will ssh connection be drop during this operation?

Comment: @alper Yes. But the convenient way to restart network interface over ssh is by doing `service network stop; sleep 5; service network start`  However, Please be careful, If you mess up your interface configuration, you might not gain back your ssh season, so be very careful.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you think it is the right way. Think, what can ubuntu do extra during booting? Ubuntu has a list of services that need to run during booting, each service has a list of consecutive command to start itself. Ubuntu just run networking service through /etc/init.d/networking  script which contains some command that need to run network service. So if any change need to apply to your network then you have to restart your service and the way is recall your service's consecutive commands.

Comment: Because rebooting is guaranteed to clear all of the interfaces that I have set up, and I'm concerned that if I remove an interface from my interfaces file, then restarting the networking script won't get rid of it.

Comment: are you sure? any change in network is worked for me with sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart.

Comment: For example, if I create a tagged vlan (e.g., eth0.123) it doesn't seem to be automatically destroyed when I restart networking

Comment: sudo eth0 down  ---  sudo eth0 up

Comment: /etc/init.d/networking re-read all network configuration file and update all settings, why should it destroy created interface? if you change your ip or dns or these kind of information then /etc/... is enough, if you create a virtual lan then you have to restart your ethernet interface(sudo eth0 down  then sudo eth0 up).

Answer (score 1):

[`/etc/network/interfaces`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man5/interfaces.5.html) controls the ifupdown tools.

So after making changes, you can just say eg `sudo ifup eth0`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually none of these work. Tested on Ubuntu 16.10. these had no effect.

- ifdown ens3 and ifup ens3
- service network stop and start
- service network reload
- systemctl stop networking.service and then start again.

Through all these the old dhcp ip came back and not the static. i wonder if this is intentional?

Answer (score 0):

Try a flush between ifup and ifdown. This worked on Mendel (Google Coral), which is a Debian based.

```
sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ip addr flush eth0 && sudo ifup eth0
```

Without the flush, the interface would restart without reading the config file.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative that worked for me:

1. Edit the /etc/network/interfaces file
2. Execute the following:

```sh
ifdown --all --allow auto
ifdown --all --allow hotplug
ifup --all --allow auto
ifup --all --allow hotplug
```